# Escaping characters in command line search and replace

Tags: osx, search

In Unix (running MacOS High Sierra), I've seen a few different search/replace (over several files) methods, e.g.:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.txt
```

or using `sed` or `grep`, etc. The problem is, how do I escape my search strings properly?  For example, if I need to replace `http://my.site/dir` with `http://new.my.site/dir`, obviously I can't include forward slashes in my search string without escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is specifically this command, note that with Perl for the `s///` operator you can choose other delimiters than `/` which then makes your life far easier as you do not have to escape anything.

Hence the following will work:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's!http://my.site/dir!http://new.my.site/dir!g;' *.txt
```

You can use any other character than `!` if you fancy it, as long as it does not appear neither in source nor replacement string. Also since the whole "script" is under `'` its content is not parsed by the shell, so you are also safe from shell interpolation of stuff like `$` and others.

See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators for all the details.

Comment: Thanks! never knew this